# How to get tsql TOP PERCENT with OFFSET

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, top, offset-fetch

```
select top 10 percent *
from sys.databases
order by database_id
```

I want to get the same 10 percent result using offset but this query works wrong

```
offset 0 rows
fetch next (select cast((count(*) * 10/100) as int ) from sys.databases) rows only
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TOP PERCENT**

> Indicates that the query returns only the first expression percent of
>   rows from the result set. Fractional values are rounded up to the next
>   integer value.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Meaning that `TOP percent` is rounding up, we could use the `CEILING()` function on a `numeric` value to get the same result.

You could change the query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.databases
ORDER BY database_id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT (SELECT CAST(CEILING((COUNT(*) * 10.0/100.0)) as int) FROM sys.databases) ROWS ONLY;
```

To get the same amount.

**Issues with applying a filter.**

If you add a where clause the results could differ, the reason being that in the changed query, you would need to add the where clause also on the query in the `OFFSET FETCH` part.

*These two queries could return different results:*

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.databases
where name not like '%A%'
ORDER BY database_id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT (SELECT CAST(CEILING((COUNT(*) * 10.0/100.0)) as int) FROM sys.databases) ROWS ONLY;


SELECT top 10 percent *
FROM sys.databases
where name not like '%A%'
ORDER BY database_id;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bb91ee7fe8d765c7e7ed456ced7a8940)

*These two queries should return the same results:*

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.databases
where name not like '%A%'
ORDER BY database_id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT (SELECT CAST(CEILING((COUNT(*) * 10.0/100.0)) as int) FROM sys.databases where name not like '%A%') ROWS ONLY;


SELECT top 10 percent *
FROM sys.databases
where name not like '%A%'
ORDER BY database_id;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ebee9fecae8ad18da66d020d3998208d)

Comment: Thank you @RandiVertongen, but why it shows different result when I apply where filter? See, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bb91ee7fe8d765c7e7ed456ced7a8940

Comment: Hey @ElGrig no problem, good question! It is because of the `SELECT CAST(CEILING((COUNT(*) * 10.0/100.0)) as int) FROM sys.databases` not having the where clause. You would need to add the same where clause to the count aswell. I will add it to the answer